# Selenium: how to get value of android 'EditText'

Tags: java, android, selenium, android-edittext

I am testing an Android application with Selenium (and Appium) in java.

My issue is that I don't know how to get the value enter in an EditText. I tried something like this:

```
AssertJUnit.assertEquals(size.getAttribute("value"),"");
```

What should I put instead of "value" to retrieve the value entered in this "size" ?

The strange thing is that I don't have any Exception raised but the System.out.println that I put right after this line is never displayed. And, at the end of the test, I have the following result:

```
Total tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
```

Any solution ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you asking how to get the current text of an ExitText? If so, EditText has a method `.getText()`, on which you can call `.toString()`.
Hope that helps.

Comment: In fact, this was not my question, I am using Selenium with Appium to test an Android application. So the code that you see there is the code of the test class not the one of the application. So I don't have access to 'EditText' class.